# Finite generation of the commutator subgroup of the pure braid group 

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, braid-groups, gr.group-theory

Let $PB_n$ be the pure braid group on $n$ strands.  The group $PB_n$ has every conceivable finiteness property.  Also, it has a large abelianization.  My question is whether the commutator subgroup $[PB_n,PB_n]$ is finitely-generated or not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, the group $PB_n$, $n\ge 3$ has an [epimorphism](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.4602v1.pdf) onto the free group $F_2$. Since the commutator subgroup $[F_2,F_2]$ is not finitely generated, the commutator subgroup $[PB_n,PB_n]$ is not finitely generated either.